# Set up Two projects VUE-JS SPA in same site it is possible?

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, url-rewriting, vue-router

I have a project in VUE JS working OK in my principal folder width this configuration .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I want add a other VUE Project in mi subfolder: [www.domain.com/SE/..](http://www.domain.com/SE/..). i have been reading and i created the next .htaccess configuration, but not work, this is subfolder .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /SE
RewriteRule ^SE/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /SE/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\SE$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\SE$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\SE/" [R=301,L]
```

I catched it in my index.js as 404

```
{
path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
component: PageNotFound,
name: "PageNotFound",
},
```

Comment: Your config looks "OK" and it should work. "I catched it in my index.js as 404" - does that not imply the request is routed to your (VUE?) project, but your project is not able to route the request (is it expecting `/SE` to be in the URL-path?). _Aside:_ You do have some errors in your config, although this does not affect your current issue.

Comment: The response of www.dominio.com/SE is querying in the main folder, i need that it is queried in the project located in subfolder

Comment: Set `DirectoryIndex index.html` (or `DirectoryIndex /SE/index.html`) at the top of the subdirectory `.htaccess` file.